# Solution to the Mukhaov equation

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I am currently trying to find solutions to the Mukhanov equation for power law potentials. My code currently looks like this,

```
#Code to compute the power spectrum from the solution to the Mukhanov equation. 
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 
plt.rcParams["font.size"] = 6
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=None)

#Define Parameters.
n = float(input('Enter the value of n: '))
k_a = np.geomspace(start = 0.005, stop = 10, num = 1000)
t = np.linspace(start = 60.0, stop = 0.0, num = 1000) #t is the efold number.
k_0 = 0.005
k_max = 1e16
#########################################
#Slow-roll parameters (using phi^2 for now and t is the e-fold number)

def ep_func(t, n):
    return (n**2)/(4*n*t + n**2)

def H_func(t, n):
    return ((2*n*t + (n**2)/2)**(n/2))/3

def eta_func(t, n):
    return 2*((2*n - n**2)/(2*n*t + ((n**2)/2)))

def a_func(t):
    return np.exp(t)
##########################################
#n_s and r

def r_func(t, n):
    return (16*(n**2))/(4*n*t + n**2)

def n_func(t, n):
    return 1 -(6*(n**2)/(4*n*t + n**2)) + (2*(n*(n-1)))/(2*n*t + (n**2)/2)

##########################################
#Create the two simplified ODE's.
#This is in terms of the e-fold number not confromal time. 
def sol(Y, t, k, ep, eta, H, a):
    return np.array([Y[1], -(3 - ep_func(t, n) + eta_func(t, n))*Y[1] -((k**2)/((a_func(t)**2)*H_func(t, n)**2))*Y[0]])
##########################################
# Find the solution using Scipy odeint function while defining the I.C's.
Yr_0 = [1/(np.sqrt(2*k_max)), 0]
Yi_0 = [0, -np.sqrt(k_max/2)]
solutions = []
# Real part of the Mukhanov equation.
for k in k_a:
    asolr = odeint(sol, Yr_0, t, args=(k, ep_func(t, n), eta_func(t, n), H_func(t, n), a_func(t)))    
    solutions.append(asolr)

# Imaginary Part of the Mukhanov equation.
for k in k_a:
    asoli = odeint(sol, Yi_0, t, args=(k, ep_func(t, n), eta_func(t, n), H_func(t, n), a_func(t)))    
solutions.append(asoli)

Yr = asolr[:,0]
Yi = asoli[:,0]
########################################## 
#Plot the solution to the mukhanov equation. 
def mukh(Yi):
    return np.absolute(Yi)
m = mukh(Yi)
plt.plot(t, m, 'r-')
plt.yscale('log') 
##########################################
#Define the the power spectrum.

#Mukhanov Power spectrum
def m_spec(k_a, Yr, Yi):
    return 2.1e-9*((k_a**3)/0.005)*(np.absolute(Yr)**2 + np.absolute(Yi)**2)

#Slow-roll power spectrum 
def s_spec(k_a, t, n):
    return 2.1e-9*(k_a/0.005)**(-(2*n**2 + n)/(2*n*t + (n**2)/2))

pm = m_spec(k_a, Yr, Yi)
ps = s_spec(k_a, t, n)

#Plot the power spectrums and parameters in subplots
fig = plt.figure()

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(k_a, pm, 'r-')
plt.title('Power spectrum P(k) for n = ' +str(n))
plt.xlabel('wavenumber (k)')
plt.ylabel('P(K)')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(k_a, ps, 'b-')
plt.title('Slow-roll Power spectrum P(k) for n = ' +str(n))
plt.xlabel('wavenumber (k)')
plt.ylabel('P(K)')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(t, H_func(t, n), 'y-')
plt.title('Epsilon Vs e-fold')
plt.xlabel('e-fold')
plt.ylabel('$H$(N)')
#plt.yscale('log')

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.plot(t, n_func(t, n), 'g-')
plt.title('$n_s$ Vs e-fold')
plt.xlabel('e-fold')
plt.ylabel('$n_s$')
#plt.yscale('log')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I have double checked and the differential equation and its initial conditions are correct. I believe the problem is with the imaginary part of the solution. I currently get an output that look like this.

[image: current output]

The problem is the top left image. I expect a straight line with a near constant gradient of about 1 that never goes much beyond 10^-9 and that clearly isn't the case.

Comment: Probably you are no longer interested in the question, but Could you improve the post by adding in LaTeX code the differential equation, and definition of quantities involved in the problem?